# Restart an Activity

Tags: android-intent, wear-os

I'm currently working on a Wear application, I display a ListView on an Activity (let's call it ActA). When the user clicks on an item, it triggers different actions on the handheld, and sends a result back to an activity on the watch (ActB). I want to update the list with this result (I need to go through the ActB for future features).

My problem is that I want to resume my ActA from ActB without restarting it. I tried using `startActivityForResult` before finding out that there's an issue with this on Wear. So I tried to use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, but the stack isn't modified. I don't have any error, nothing, just my ActB displayed and doing nothing.

Does anyone has an idea or any information about a different activity stack on Wear ?

**EDIT**
Forgot to say that when using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, `finish()` which is called just below isn't executed.

Comment: I have a very similar situation. Anyone?

Comment: @AlejandroCasas I've conducted some more tests, it seems like the activity stack is totally different on Wear, even the activity lifecycle is slightly different. So for now, apart from restarting your activity and using carefully the extras as flags, I don't really know what to do... Did you have any breaktrhought ?

Comment: @Snow Have you figured out the activity stack/life cycle on wearable? I cannot find related documentation anywhere.